# Oracle Data Provider - call ExecuteReader to get OUT parameters

Tags: c#, oracle, oledb, odp.net, odp

I am refactoring an existing application to change the Oracle Data Provider from OLE DB to the Managed Oracle Data Provider (ODP).

I need to call the following stored procedure, which has several input parameters, and several OUT parameters which are basically of type TABLE of VARCHAR2

```
PROCEDURE RetrieveInfo(
p_vParam1               IN          Varchar2,
p_vParam2               IN          Varchar2,
p_vParam3               IN          Varchar2,
p_vParam4               IN          Varchar2,
MARK_CODE               OUT NOCOPY  g_tMarkCd,  
EQPUN_NBR               OUT NOCOPY  g_tEqpunNbr,
CSTMR _ID               OUT NOCOPY  g_tCstmrId,
CNSGN_CSTMR_ID          OUT NOCOPY  g_tCstmrId,
SHPR_CSTMR_ID           OUT NOCOPY  g_tCstmrId);
```

where `TYPE g_tMarkCd IS TABLE OF my_table.my_varchar_column%TYPE` (and the other types are similar).

Unfortunately the procedure does not return a Ref Cursor.

OLE DB:

The existing code sets up a OleDbCommand with CommandType of Text, and CommandText is set to

```
"{call MY_SCHEMA.RetrieveInfo(?,?,?,?,{resultset 10000,MARK_CODE,EQPUN_NBR,SHPR_CSTMR_ID,CNSGN_CSTMR_ID,CSTMR_ID})}"
```

Then the proc is called by adding the four input OleDbParameter to the OleDbCommand object (but **not** adding any OUT parameters), and then calling the OleDbCommand ExecuteReader() method. Everything works with OLE DB. The resulting IDataReader has fields for each of the output parameters.

ODP:

ODP does not support the SQL syntax (so I set the OracleCommand CommandText to the name of the proc and set CommandType to StoredProcedure).

**Is there a way to set the C# client code up in a way that I can call the OracleCommand ExecuteReader() method in the same way as with OLE DB?**

(If I have to explicitly set the OUT variables as parameters in the command, then the system is going to need a major rewrite, which I would want to avoid if at all possible.)

EDIT: The (to be deprecated) OLEDB code looked like

```
objCommand = new OleDbCommand(); 
objCommand.Connection = oledbConnection; 
objCommand.CommandText = "{call MY_SCHEMA.RetrieveInfo(?,?,?,?,{resultset 10000,MARK_CODE,EQPUN_NBR,SHPR_CSTMR_ID,CNSGN_CSTMR_ID,CSTMR_ID})}";
objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 

objCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input, 2000, value)); 
// repeat for the other input parameters, but not output parameters
IDataReader rdr = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
// the resulting data reader has field count = 5
```

Comment: Please show your C# code which generates the OracleCommand and Parameters.

Comment: The (VB.Net) code is:          
         
objCommand = New OracleCommand
With objCommand
                .Connection = oracleConnection
                .CommandText = "MY_SCHEMA.RetrieveInfo"
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
End With               

And the parameters are added to the command in the usual way:
   objCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input, 2000, value))

Comment: Your provided code is in contradiction to your question where you say "OleDbCommand with CommandType of Text". Here you create a `OracleCommand` with CommandType of StoredProcedure!

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit My question relates to moving the code to ODP - hence the use of OracleCommand

Comment: Show the existing old code